# can you use a modal to open when you click on a last child element insted of haveing a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a face matching game and im not sure what else to do to assign the modal to have a reset button in it so they can play the game again since you have to currently refresh the page to play again or is there an easier way to have something similar to a alert message that can have a restart button?

```
<title>Matching Game</title>
    <style>
        img{
            position: absolute;
        }

        div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        #rightSide {
            left: 500px;
            border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        alert{
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font: darkred;
            background-size:400px;
        }
        h1{
            font-size: Verdana
        }
    
        title{
            margin:auto;
            padding:auto;
            border:rgb(11, 158, 11) solid 3px;
            background-position:center;
        }
    
        html{
            border:rounded_corner;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-style:stripes;
        }

        .modal{
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: rgb(112, 9, 9);
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        }

        .modal-content {
            background-color: #0a76f1;
            margin: 15% auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(182, 22, 161);
            width: 80%;
        }

        .close {
            color: rgb(73, 73, 35);
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: burlywood;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload='generateFaces()'>
  <h1>'Matching Game'</h1>
  <p>'Click on the extra face on the left.'<p>
  <div id='leftSide'></div>
  <div id='rightSide'></div>
  <button id='myBtn'>Restart</button>
  <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <span class='close'>&times;</span>
    <p>'GaMe OvEr!' + num + '!\n Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum.'</p>
  </div>

  </div>
  <script>
      let numberOfFaces = 5;

      const theLeftSide= document.getElementById('leftSide');
      const theRightSide= document.getElementById('rightSide');
  

      function generateFaces(){
          for (let i=0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            const face= document.createElement('img');
            face.src= 'image/smile.png';
            const randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
            const randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) +1;
            face.style.top = randomTop + 'px';
            face.style.left = randomLeft + 'px';
            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
          }

          const leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
          leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
          theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
          theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);
          document.body.addEventListener('click', gameOver);
      }
        let num = 0;
      function nextLevel() {
          event.stopPropagation();
          num = num + 1;
          numberOfFaces += 5;
          while (theLeftSide.lastChild) {
              theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.lastChild);
          }
          while (theRightSide.lastChild){
              theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild);
          }
          generateFaces();
      }

      function gameOver() {
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
          var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
          var span = document.getElementById('close')[0];
          btn.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = 'block';
          }
          span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = 'none';
          }
          window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                  modal.style.display = 'none';
              }
          }
          document.body.removeEventListener('click', gameOver);
          theLeftSide.lastChild.removeEventListener('click', nextLevel);
      
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a confirm box

```
function askRestart() {
  if (confirm("Do you want to play again?")) {
    generateFaces();
  } else {
    //whatever
  }
}
```

If you really need to reload the page you can call

```
location.reload();
```

instead of generatefaces();